# Issue using cocos2dx ui::TextField : textfield is not proper show in android device

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

> textfield only show top upper side in android  my textfield is working
>   proper in ios device but android device it is display upper top side i
>   have attach screenshot

```
auto namewithPlates =  ui::Scale9Sprite::create("text_field.png");
        namewithPlates->setAnchorPoint(Point(.53,.5));


        auto tempplt =  ui::Scale9Sprite::create("text_field.png");
        tempplt->setScale(ratinaScaleX);

        f_editemail = ui::EditBox::create(tempplt->getBoundingBox().size, namewithPlates);



        f_editemail->setPosition(Point(plates->getPosition().x,signwithPlates->getPosition().y-signwithPlates->getBoundingBox().size.height/2 -tempplt->getBoundingBox().size.height/2));//added 11 Aug 2015s



        f_editemail->setFont(fRockoUltraFLFBold, 20*ratinaScaleX);//Added 11 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setPlaceholderFont(fRockoUltraFLFBold, 20*ratinaScaleX);//Added 11 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setPlaceHolder("Email");
        f_editemail->setPlaceholderFontColor(Color3B::RED);
        f_editemail->setFontColor(TextColor);////Added 11 Aug 2015
        mainLayer->addChild(f_editemail);
        f_editemail->setLocalZOrder(4);//added 10 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setReturnType(ui::EditBox::KeyboardReturnType::DONE);
    auto namewithPlates =  ui::Scale9Sprite::create("text_field.png");
        namewithPlates->setAnchorPoint(Point(.53,.5));


        auto tempplt =  ui::Scale9Sprite::create("text_field.png");
        tempplt->setScale(ratinaScaleX);

        f_editemail = ui::EditBox::create(tempplt->getBoundingBox().size, namewithPlates);



        f_editemail->setPosition(Point(visibleSize/2));//added 11 Aug 2015s



        f_editemail->setFont(fRockoUltraFLFBold, 20*ratinaScaleX);//Added 11 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setPlaceholderFont(fRockoUltraFLFBold, 20*ratinaScaleX);//Added 11 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setPlaceHolder("Email");
        f_editemail->setPlaceholderFontColor(Color3B::RED);
        f_editemail->setFontColor(TextColor);////Added 11 Aug 2015
        mainLayer->addChild(f_editemail);
        f_editemail->setLocalZOrder(4);//added 10 Aug 2015
        f_editemail->setReturnType(ui::EditBox::KeyboardReturnType::DONE);
    }
```

**1.image1 is ios screenshot[image]**

**2.image2 is android device[image]**

Comment: What's the engine version? I suggest you to give Editbox a try, it has better implementation and in v3.8.1  the EditBox on Andorid platform is even better than before.

Comment: i have use v3.6, ok i will try v3.8.1